# How can I repair a bad upgrade in Fedora 30

Tags: fedora, package-management, upgrade, dnf

I was upgrading my computer from Fedora 30 to Fedora 31 using

```
$ sudo dnf upgrade --refresh
```

when it hang and rebooted. Since that whenever I call

```
$ sudo dnf upgrade --refresh
```

it gives me this error:

> Total                                                                                                                                    262 kB/s |  31 MB     02:02
>   Delta RPMs reduced 416.0 MB of updates to 361.4 MB (13.1% saved)
>   Running transaction check
>   Transaction check succeeded.
>   Running transaction test
>   The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
>   You can remove cached packages by executing 'dnf clean packages'.
>   Error: Transaction test error:
>     file /usr/share/doc/libpcap/CHANGES from install of libpcap-14:1.9.1-1.fc30.i686 conflicts with file from package libpcap-14:1.9.0-3.fc30.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/doc/libpcap/CREDITS from install of libpcap-14:1.9.1-1.fc30.i686 conflicts with file from package libpcap-14:1.9.0-3.fc30.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/man/man7/pcap-filter.7.gz from install of libpcap-14:1.9.1-1.fc30.i686 conflicts with file from package libpcap-14:1.9.0-3.fc30.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/man/man7/pcap-linktype.7.gz from install of libpcap-14:1.9.1-1.fc30.i686 conflicts with file from package libpcap-14:1.9.0-3.fc30.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/man/man7/pcap-tstamp.7.gz from install of libpcap-14:1.9.1-1.fc30.i686 conflicts with file from package libpcap-14:1.9.0-3.fc30.x86_64

I have tried to read solutions to this and used commands like `sudo dnf remove --duplicates`, `sudo dnf autoremove`, `sudo dnf update --skip-broken`, `sudo dnf update --refresh --allowerasing`, `sudo dnf distro-sync`, but none of these worked.

Comment: are you able to remove `libpcap-14:1.9.1-1.fc30.i686` without removing/breaking something important? if so, is that libpcap conflict the only problem?